# Git Revision Graph Incorrect

Tags: git, github, revision-graph

I've a couple of repo's that contain a master and dev branch.  Master represents releases while dev represents the current buildable version.  There are also a number of other branches for features which are deleted after merging to dev.

I've recently changed to using the pull request workflow, before that, I performed squashed merges.  Some repos are new and have always used the pull request workflow, however, one of the older repos (and most important) used the squashed merge.  The revision graph looks like this

[image]

At this point, all changes have been committed and pull requests used to merge the changes. Ignoring customs and collections I'd expect a revision graph like this:

[image]

My questions are:

- Is there anything wrong with the first revision graph?
- How could I get the graph to be more like the second?

Comment: A branch never points to another branch. A branch only points to a commit as in your first figure.

Comment: I thought upstream IS origin

Comment: This is a forked repo - upstream is the original, origin is my fork

Comment: @RickardKörkkö, I realise that branches only reference commits - so in both revision graphs everything is pointing to the same commit.  I’m just curious why the layout is different?

Comment: Given that branches only point to commits, the second one would be lying. Why would you expect or want a lying layout?

Comment: @8bittree, I understand your point. My understanding is that both diagrams say the same thing, however the second one is neater - as in dev points to the same commit as master - just don’t understand why the layout is different

Comment: But they don't say the same thing. In the former, a change to which commit master points to would have no effect on dev. In the latter, it looks like changes to master would also change dev.

Answer (score 1):

Git actually *does* have symbolic references, in which one reference contains the *name* of another reference, rather than its value.

Until relatively recently, these mostly didn't work,<sup>1</sup> except for the specific case of `HEAD`.  The main `HEAD` is normally a symbolic reference to some other branch name.  The `git checkout` command, or the new `git switch` in Git 2.23 and newer, manages this symbolic reference for you.

Meanwhile, reach *remote*, such as `origin` can have a symbolic HEAD, e.g., `origin/HEAD -> origin/master`.  Your Git sets these up based on the results it gets when it asks the Git at the URL—the `origin` Git in this case—what branch *its* `HEAD` named.  If *their* `HEAD` was a symbolic reference to *their* `master`, your `origin/HEAD` should be a symbolic reference to your `origin/master`.

But apart from these cases, each reference just holds a raw hash ID.  The best<sup>2</sup> way to *draw* this is to draw the reference holding the hash ID, or pointing to the Git object selected by that hash ID.  Only symbolic references should be drawn as pointing to another reference.

---

<sup>1</sup>Try creating symbolic branch `sym` containing just-created branch name `br`:

```
git branch br
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/sym refs/heads/br
```

List the branches with `git branch` to make sure it worked.  Now ask Git to delete branch `sym`:

```
git branch -d sym
```

Old versions of Git would delete branch `br`!  If your Git deleted `sym`, you have a Git in which these symbolic refs work better.

<sup>2</sup>*Best* is, of course, a matter of opinion, but since I'm writing this answer, I get to use *my* opinion. :-)